# Hide child menu item based on a class name

Tags: fix-my-code, menu-item

I have the following Menu structure:

Genre
- Fiction
- Autobiography
- Sci Fi
- Other [class="hide"]

The menu created is then /genre/fiction/*, /genre/other/*. I am trying to not display the /other within the list of menu items which I can easily do by using JavaScript to hide the parent list item. But this is still visible to the crawlers which I am trying to avoid. I could put it under an unpublished/hidden menu but that would mean i loose the top level 'genre' since the /other will become top level since Other won't have any parent.

So the only method I can imagine is to create a mod_menu override (default_url.php) and check for a class set in the backend and if the class is set for any menu item, do not display it.

Where would the if/else condition go in the following code for it to not appear or at the very least; for there to be no link even if the text is displayed? I tried putting it in line 4 but all the links simply turned into a link to the homepage.

```
    switch ($item->browserNav) :
    default:
    case 0:
?><a <?php echo $class; ?>href="<?php echo $flink; ?>" <?php echo $title; ?>><?php echo $linktype; ?></a><?php
        break;
    case 1:
        // _blank
?><a <?php echo $class; ?>href="<?php echo $flink; ?>" target="_blank" <?php echo $title; ?>><?php echo $linktype; ?></a><?php
        break;
    case 2:
        // window.open
        $options = 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,'.$params->get('window_open');
            ?><a <?php echo $class; ?>href="<?php echo $flink; ?>" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','<?php echo $options;?>');return false;" <?php echo $title; ?>><?php echo $linktype; ?></a><?php
        break;
endswitch;
```

Comment: Are you using $class? Because that's going to give if class="class" rather than if class
What was the syntax you used for the if statement?

Comment: Yep I was outputting the $class and now you said it, I noticed it as well. I support I will have to extract the class information from that $class string and do my thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method you're going with here, this is how I would imagine achieving this;

1. First of all, there's a possibility that your menu name might have multiple classes, so you need to check if your class name is is *contained within* `$class`, as opposed to exactly equal to it.  You could do this with PHP's `strpos` function (though be careful about partial matches - more on that later).
2. Now, because your switch statement appears to output a different variation of the same menu item (based on where the link is opening), you probably want to wrap the entire statement in an `if` clause to check against the class name - rather than just a subsection of it;

   ```
   $class = "apples oranges pears"; // contains 3 different classes

   if (strpos($class, "oranges") !== false)
   {
       // DON'T show the menu item, because 'oranges' was detected
   }
   else
   {
       // your whole switch statement goes here
       switch ($item->browserNav) :
          // blah blah blah ...
       endswitch;
   }
   ```

Be aware that `strpos` will need to evaluate to EXACTLY 'not false', (!==) as opposed to basic 'not false' (!=), because it will incorrectly interpret position 0 as false if you don't.

Regarding partial class matches - if, in the example above, you were looking for a class called `pea`, it would still match against `peaches`, so the simplest solution is just to make sure that your class name is sufficiently distinct - otherwise you will need to write more elaborate code (maybe using regular expressions, or some other useful function that I can't think of right away).

Hope that's of some use.

Answer (score 2):

> But this is still visible to the crawlers which I am trying to avoid.

Each menu item has a "Robots" option on the "Metadata" tab. Set it to "No index, no follow" and search engines should not index your page anymore.